# Objective-c and JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, api

I am fairly new at objective C. I am writing an app that is going to validate a username and password in a MySQL database, and I think I should use JSON to connect to the API that is going to be written for it. I've been looking on the internet, and can't find any good resources on where to start with this. Does anybody have any good resources, or is it better to use a different validation method?

Comment: If the API is remote then JSON is the format of choice.  If local, and you're trying to avoid having a method with a dozen separate parms, use an NS(Mutable)Dictionary to contain the parm data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, what you want to do is something like:

Create an `NSDictionary` that has 2 key/value pairs, like

```
@{ 
    @"username":@"someUser",
    @"password":@"hunter2"
}
```

Then use `-[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject...:]` to turn that dictionary into an `NSData` object. This will contain the formatted JSON hash suitable for sending your API request.

You'll probably want to look at `NSURLRequest` for sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`NSJSONSerialization` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) to encode and decode JSON.